# I have resigned as moderator

Tags: discussion, moderators

A year after I was elected as moderator it turned out it was not *for* a year. I was stretched thin and threw a fit in the mod room. :) Still somehow I went on to serve as a mod for nearly five years more.

Recently I had not been as involved and plugged in into daily happenings of the stack. In part it just had been a long time to keep doing it. And in part my attention in WordPress space went to other things.

I had also noticed that in trying to bring historical perspective to discussions I started to just... drag old baggage into them. A sign of need for fresher touch.

I think I had a long enough run and it is time to part with my moderator diamond.

My work at this site remains an accomplishment I am *immensely* proud of and I will still be around. Just at more relaxed pace of my own.

I wish good luck to all current and future moderators! I had never been a part of better and smoother moderation process and Stack Exchange is doing it very right as for me.

Comment: This makes me sad, honestly. But I understand your perspective. Thanks for everything you did and for the good look.

Comment: Thanks for all your hard work, Rarst! Much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for all your participation! Hopefully you'll stick around the community though, I love reading the discussions!

Comment: Thanks for all your time and everything you did in this context. All the Best for the future.

Comment: Really appreciate all the work you put in for the StackExchange community man **[raise glass]**

Comment: Thank you for everything, Rarst! You definitely should be proud; your contributions to WPSE are god-like. Your work here and elsewhere in the WP community has been an inspiration to me for years on end.

Comment: An upvote, not because you're resigning, but because it's "Rarst" - one of my mentors in WPSE. Good luck to you always. <3

Comment: Since you have labelled your post 'discussion' I suppose we can still make you change your mind?

Comment: @cjbj nah, you just have to pick one tag on meta to classify :)

Comment: And you don't consider your leaving a 'bug'? ;-)

Comment: You're an inspiration to us all @rarst

Comment: Thanks very much for all your help.

Comment: @Rarst, you've been a great moderator and your knowledge of WordPress seems encyclopedic. Thanks for everything and best wishes.

Answer (score 24):

Thank you for all the work you have done for us!

When I became a moderator and got a look at the history behind the scenes, I realized how much and how lonely you have been working. Very impressive!

I'm grateful that you didn't throw the towel back in these days. You have been the the most reliable moderator to ask questions and discuss issues over the following years.

I hope to see you in Vienna or Paris later this year. :)

Comment: Paris for sure, always WCEU. :)

Answer (score 11):

I'm not going to lament about your resignation. You did great work here we can all be very thankful for. But especially when it comes to voluntary work just as important as doing it is to be aware of your personal limits and to know when to take a step back. And nobody knows better when that moment has come than oneself.

So thank you for your work here (as well as for all the other work in the community) and all the best for whatever will be next.

Answer (score 9):

Thank you for a great time, tough discussions and your strong opinion on … everything. Your continuous work here really made this site a better place.

I am thankful for all we accomplished here together. It would not have been possible without you and your contributions will not be forgotten.

Answer (score 6):

I won't say `thank you`. Instead, let me say a few words as a new member in WordPress StackExchange site.

I've joined & decided to become an active member of WP SE site very recently. I've been in the receiving end of SE WordPress site (& SE in general) for many years (mainly from Google Searches) and recently realized it's about time I contribute some back into this wonderful community.

While gaining 10/20/30 `rep` points from each of my contributions, I realized how much effort you guys have put into this site to make it so successful. To put things into perspective, if I continue at my current pace, it'll take me around 30 years to gain the same amount of `rep` points you have at this very moment!

Needless to say, I have a huge amount of resect for you & out of that respect, I promise to continue my contribution at least until I gain the same amount of `rep` points (about 75k) you have now (if I'm alive & well till then). This is the minimum I can do to honour the outstanding contribution of people like you. I'm sure many more will follow.

Hope to see you around for many more years to come. All the best.

Comment: Welcome to the site! I just want to say — don’t sweat the points. They are a nice tasty bit of gamification, but what really matters is that you _want_ to contribute and it's good both for you and for people who will benefit from your knowledge down the road.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I wasn't really focusing on the `rep` points. I'm here to contribute back to the community that I've received so much from. I mentioned `rep` just as a point of reference, nothing more.

Answer (score 5):

Some time ago I was at the Yoast premises in Wychen, the Netherlands. Joost and I talked about his company and the future of WordPress. Somewhere along Joost noted that while most of his programmers were right there in Wychen, he sometimes engaged other coders. Most notably, he said, some guy from the Ukraine who was just amazing at WP.

Just telling you, so you guys know Andrey's fame stretches beyond WPSE...

Comment: Well, I wouldn't quite call it a "fame" reference having worked with them for two years... :)

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for five great years! Stick around!

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the inspiring answers, the great "make sense of" and all the stuffs that ARE significant contributions to WordPress.

Answer (score 3):

Many of my questions which first lead me to WPSE were addressed by your answers. When I finally created an account, I often looked to your posts and general conduct as models for my own. While I haven't said much in our chatroom on the whole, I've spent a great deal of time lurking, and have learned a substantial amount regarding good development practices and deeper insights into WordPress and PHP from reading over your conversations; not to mention following your articles on your blog, and WordCamp presentations (when I could dig them up on the 'net). I got many answers to questions I would have never thought to ask, and many more prompts to pursue others. You may not have known it, but you've been pretty integral to my entire WordPress learning experience in the more than five years since it began.

So, really, I guess *this is your fault* - thanks for dragging me down the rabbit hole, Rarst -_-

I look forward to seeing whatever you take on with your newly freed time, and hope to catch you around down the road. Thanks for everything you've given me, and everything you've done for the WPSE and WordPress communities over the years. Cheers, Rarst - I hope you're getting some well deserved rest =D

Answer (score 2):

I have been reading your answers and will continue... 
Thanks for your time...

Answer (score 2):

Rarst from what I saw you are so unselfish and willing to share the knowledge.

I wish you the best luck in this world whatever you plan and possible as an entrepreneur.